# Creating a back top button in wiki TOC

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, wiki-pages

I am using a script for wiki TOC and its working great. I want to add a back to top button in the body of the wiki, however, my code is flawed! Can someone help me?

```
 <!-- SharePoint WIKI Table of Contents. Sunnyape, August 2013 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTOC() {
document.getElementById("theTOC").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("hide").style.display = 'none';
}
function showTOC() {
document.getElementById("theTOC").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("hide").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
<div id="wikiTOC">
<table style="padding: 2px;"><tr>
<td><div class="TOCheader">Table of Contents</div></td>
<td>
<div id="show" onclick="showTOC()">[Show]</div>
<div id="hide" onclick="hideTOC()">[Hide]</div>
</td>
</table>
 <br>
<div id='theTOC'>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var L1=0, L2=0, L3=0;
$(".ms-wikicontent H1, .ms-wikicontent H2, .ms-wikicontent H3").each(function(i){
 theLevel=$(this).get(0).tagName;
 if (theLevel=="H1") {
  L1=L1+1;
  L2=0;
  L3=0;
  theLevelString=""+L1;
  }
 else if (theLevel=="H2") {
  L2=L2+1;
  L3=0;
  theLevelString=""+L1+"."+L2;
  }
 else {
  L3=L3+1;
  theLevelString=""+L1+"."+L2+"."+L3;
  }
 $(this).attr("id", "heading_" + i);
 $("#theTOC").append("<a href='#heading_" + i + "' title='" + theLevel + "'>" + " " + $(this).text() + "</a><br />");
});
});
showTOC();
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if($("#_wikiPageMode").attr('value') !== "Edit") {
$(document).ready(function(){$("<a href='#wikiTOC' style='text-decoration:none;'> [Back to Top]</a>").appendTo(".wiki-body h1");});
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.ms-wikicontent H1 {color:black !important; background-color:#96cfff !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight:bold !important; padding: 2px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent H2 {color:black !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:15px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent p  {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent li {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent tr {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
#wikiTOC {font-family: "Segoe UI"; background-color: white; float: left; padding: 5px; padding-top: 0px;}
#wikiTOC .TOCheader {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding: 1px;}
#wikiTOC .closehide {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;}
#wikiTOC a[title=H1] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:13px; font-weight: normal;}
#wikiTOC a[title=H2] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:13px; font-weight: normal; margin-left: 20px; line-height:140%}
#wikiTOC a[title=H3] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:11px; font-weight: normal; margin-left: 40px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a website where you found this code that you could reference? Also do you have the site feature called "Minimal Download Strategy" disabled? (I found that it sometimes causes issues with code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify the code as below and add the code into script editor web part.

```
<style>
.ms-wikicontent H1 {color:black !important; background-color:#96cfff !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight:bold !important; padding: 2px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent H2 {color:black !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:15px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent p  {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent li {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
.ms-wikicontent tr {color:gray !important; background-color:white !important; font-size:13px !important;}
#wikiTOC {font-family: "Segoe UI"; background-color: white; float: left; padding: 5px; padding-top: 0px;}
#wikiTOC .TOCheader {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding: 1px;}
#wikiTOC .closehide {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;}
#wikiTOC a[title=H1] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:13px; font-weight: normal;}
#wikiTOC a[title=H2] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:13px; font-weight: normal; margin-left: 20px; line-height:140%}
#wikiTOC a[title=H3] {font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size:11px; font-weight: normal; margin-left: 40px;}
</style>
<!-- SharePoint WIKI Table of Contents. Sunnyape, August 2013 -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var L1=0, L2=0, L3=0;   
    if($("#_wikiPageMode").val()!== "Edit") {
        $("<a href='#wikiTOC' style='text-decoration:none;'> [Back to Top]</a>").appendTo(".ms-wikicontent");
    }

    $(".ms-wikicontent H1, .ms-wikicontent H2, .ms-wikicontent H3").each(function(i){
        theLevel=$(this).get(0).tagName;
        if (theLevel=="H1") {
            L1=L1+1;
            L2=0;
            L3=0;
            theLevelString=""+L1;
        }else if (theLevel=="H2") {
            L2=L2+1;
            L3=0;
            theLevelString=""+L1+"."+L2;
        }else {
            L3=L3+1;
            theLevelString=""+L1+"."+L2+"."+L3;
        }
        $(this).attr("id", "heading_" + i);
        $("#theTOC").append("<a href='#heading_" + i + "' title='" + theLevel + "'>" + " " + $(this).text() + "</a><br />");
    });
    showTOC();
});
function hideTOC() {
    $("#theTOC").hide();
    $("#show").show();
    $("#hide").hide();
}
function showTOC() {
    $("#theTOC").show();
    $("#show").hide();
    $("#hide").show();
}
</script>

<div id="wikiTOC">
    <table style="padding: 2px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="TOCheader">Table of Contents</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="show" onclick="showTOC()">[Show]</div>
                <div id="hide" onclick="hideTOC()">[Hide]</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div id='theTOC'>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked great! Could you tell me what was wrong?

Comment: In my test, the ".wiki-body h1" is not exists, so, the code not working.